# wait for another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

So I have this program that attempts to establish communication between two different threads, thread1 and thread2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Project1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void thread1() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 1, so we now print 2");
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 2, so we now print 3");
        }

        public static void thread2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 1, so we now print 1");
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 2, so we now print 2");
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 3, so we now print 3");
        }

        public static void Main() {

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => thread1()));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => thread2()));
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t2.Join();
            t1.Join();

        }

    }
}
```

However, I want it to occur such that this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("1");
```

...gets executed first, while thread2 merely waits for this line to be executed. Then and only then would it print:

```
Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 1, so we now print 1");
```

After this line is printed, then and only then would this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 1, so we now print 2");
```

...get printed, and so on. So I want to change the code, so that the threads to communicate with each other so that the lines get printed in this order:

```
            Console.WriteLine("1"); // from t1
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 1, so we now print 1"); // from t2
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 1, so we now print 2"); // from t1
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 2, so we now print 2"); // from t2
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 2, so we now print 3"); // from t1
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 3, so we now print 3"); // from t2
```

I understand what lock does, but it only applies if the two different threads are running on the same function. However, here, the two functions are different and thus I can't use lock here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note on lock, as I mentioned below, your threads do not need to be in the same function.  Locks can be used to synchronize threads **as long as they are running in the same process**.  If you are trying to synchronize threads in different processes (e.g. synchronize two different programs), you'll need to use a Mutex.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you need [Monitor.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait) and [Monitor.Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse).  There's a [free eBook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_How_to_Use_Wait_and_Pulse) out there on Threading (there are probably many but this one helped me).

You can use a static object to lock on, and then have your threads call `Monitor.Pulse` to signal that they are "done with their turn" and `Monitor.Wait` to "wait for their next turn".  Here's an example implementation using your basic code:

```
public class Class1
{
     // Use this to syncrhonize threads
    private static object SyncRoot = new object();
     // First "turn" goes to thread 1
    private static int threadInControl = 1;

    public static void thread1()
    {
        lock(SyncRoot) // Request exclusive access to SyncRoot
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            GiveTurnTo(2); // Let thread 2 have a turn
            WaitTurn(1);   // Wait for turn to be given to thread 1
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 1, so we now print 2");
            GiveTurnTo(2); // Let thread 2 have a turn
            WaitTurn(1);   // Wait for turn to be given to thread 1
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 2, so we now print 3");
            GiveTurnTo(2); // Let thread 2 have a turn
        }
    }

    public static void thread2()
    {
        lock(SyncRoot) // Request exclusive access to SyncRoot
        {
            WaitTurn(2);   // Wait for turn to be given to thread 2
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 1, so we now print 1");
            GiveTurnTo(1); // Let thread 1 have a turn
            WaitTurn(2);   // Wait for turn to be given to thread 2
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 2, so we now print 2");
            GiveTurnTo(1); // Let thread 1 have a turn
            WaitTurn(2);   // Wait for turn to be given to thread 2
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 3, so we now print 3");
            GiveTurnTo(1); // Let thread 1 have a turn
        }
    }

    // Wait for turn to use SyncRoot object
    public static void WaitTurn(int threadNum)
    {
        // While( not this threads turn )
        while (threadInControl != threadNum)
        {
            // "Let go" of lock on SyncRoot and wait utill 
            // someone finishes their turn with it
            Monitor.Wait(SyncRoot);
        }
    }

    // Pass turn over to other thread
    public static void GiveTurnTo(int nextThreadNum)
    {
        threadInControl = nextThreadNum;
        // Notify waiting threads that it's someone else's turn
        Monitor.Pulse(SyncRoot);
    }

    public static void  void Main()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Class1.thread1()));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Class1.thread2()));
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t2.Join();
        t1.Join();
    }
}
```

As for using the [lock keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), it is not limited to synchronization within the same function.  Lock "guarantees" exclusive access to a resource (object) to a single thread (by exclusive, I mean that only one thread can obtain a lock on that resource at a time, locking does not prevent other threads from simply accessing the object itself).

To simplify it, `lock(someObject)` is like a thread getting in line to use `someOject` and then waiting until all other threads in front of it have finished their turn before continuing.  A thread ends its "turn" when it leaves the scope of the lock statement (unless you add things like `Monitor.Pulse` or `Monitor.Wait`).

Answer (score 3):

Use a ManualResetEvent. Wait for it in thread 2 and set it in thread1 after Console.WriteLn()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

Comment: the link goes to "Page not Found"

Comment: You'd need to ensure that thread 1 then waits for thread 2, which would require two ManualResetEvents, one for each thread.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Helped a lot in my solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Project1
{
    class Class1
    {
        private static ManualResetEvent mre1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent mre2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public static void thread1() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            mre2.Set();
            mre1.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 1, so we now print 2");
            mre2.Set();
            mre1.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 2, so we now print 3");
        }

        public static void thread2()
        {
            mre2.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 1, so we now print 1");
            mre1.Set();
            mre2.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 2, so we now print 2");
            mre1.Set();
            mre2.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 3, so we now print 3");
        }

        public static void Main() {

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => thread1()));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => thread2()));

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();

            while (true) {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks guys. I think I have the solution now!

Comment: Please accept a solution on this page if you have figured out the answer to your problem (it *can* be your own solution if you so choose, although it appears that @Kell's answer was the one that got you here).

Answer (score 1):

From the example given in the [Two-Way Signaling and Races](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_TwoWay_Signaling_and_Races) section of the Signaling with Wait and Pulse section contained in the Advanced Threading tutorial by Mr. Joe Albahari:

```
static readonly object locker = new object();
private static bool ready, go;

public static void Thread1()
{
  IEnumerable<Action> actions = new List<Action>()
  {
   () => Console.WriteLine("1"),
   () => Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 1, so we now print 2"),
   () => Console.WriteLine("t2 has printed 2, so we now print 3")
  };

  foreach (var action in actions)
  {
    lock (locker)
    {
      while (!ready) Monitor.Wait(locker);
      ready = false;
      go = true;
      Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
      action();
    } 
  }
}

public static void Thread2()
{
  IEnumerable<Action> actions = new List<Action>()
  {
   () => Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 1, so we now print 1"),
   () => Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 2, so we now print 2"),
   () => Console.WriteLine("t1 has printed 3, so we now print 3")
  };

  foreach (var action in actions)
  {
    lock (locker)
    {
      ready = true;
      Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
      while (!go) Monitor.Wait(locker);
      go = false;
      action();
    }
  }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Thread1()));
  Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Thread2()));
  t1.Start();
  t2.Start();
  t2.Join();
  t1.Join();
}
```

Comment: Nice way to take the `Monitor.Pulse()` and `Monitor.Wait()` idea and reduce the amount of code it takes to add more actions.