# How to synchronize threads so that they respond to user input?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I have an assignment from school to program a guessing game. The player/user connects to the `server`, starts the game and guesses a word. If he guesses the word, he wins. Multiple players/users can join the game(Later I will limit to a reasonable number, like 3). Client connects via `putty`

In this task I need to use multiple `threads` and then synchronize them somehow. Let's take into account that there are 3 players playing. The first player guesses, enters his guess, and I want the other two players to wait while the player enters his guess. Then the 2nd player can guess, after the 2nd player the 3rd player, etc..

**My primary guess**
a) How do I do this? I used `Join`, but I don't know if it accomplishes what I want

b)Is this style of play(Waiting for players to next guess) at all good for the example with thread work?

**Server** class:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Constuctor for creating server for players. 
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="port">
        /// Port for connecting to the server
        /// 
        /// </param>
        public Server(int port)
        {
            myServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            myServer.Start();
            isRunning = true;
            LoopServer();
        }
```

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Every time a new user connects to the server, a new thread is created.
        /// </summary>
        private void LoopServer()
        {
            while (isRunning)
            {
                TcpClient client = myServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoopClient));
                thread.Start(client);
                thread.Join();
            }
        }
```

```
/// <summary>
       /// Method where is game played
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="obj"></param>
        private void LoopClient(object obj)
        {
           
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                users.Add(new User(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                writer.Flush();

                puzzle.guessWord( writer, reader,users );
                Console.WriteLine("Out of the server");



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Game** class:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Everytime player/user take guess, the strign is added to list of user's gusses
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user">
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="userGuess"></param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns what is user's guess(string) and who took the guess(id)
        /// </returns>
        public string TakeGuess(User user, string userGuess)
        {
            user.Guesses.Add(Validation(userGuess));
            return "Your guess:" + userGuess + " " + "player with id:" + user.Id;
        }
```

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Here is the method in which the game itself is played.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="writer"></param>
        /// <param name="reader"></param>
        /// <param name="users"></param>
        public void guessWord(StreamWriter writer, StreamReader reader, List<User> users)
        {
            Console.Write("Connected");
            bool gameIsPlaying = true;
            //Creates new User. The player's id indicates which thread the player is using
            User user = new User(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            writer.WriteLine("Guessing game");

            Console.WriteLine("Number of players in game:" + " "+  users.Count);
            if (users.Count > 0)
            {
                while (gameIsPlaying)
                {
                    string data = reader.ReadLine();
                    //Whatever what writer object print, shows on client side(in putty)
                    writer.WriteLine(TakeGuess(user, data));

                    if (Validation(data).Equals(this.Word))
                    {
                        gameIsPlaying = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Winner is user with id" + " " + user.Id);
                        writer.WriteLine("Winner is user with id"+ " " + user.Id);
                        users.Clear();
                    }


                }

                writer.WriteLine("The game is over");

            }
        }
```

I have tried to synchronize threads(platers/users as I have described in the text above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your homework, so I'll just give a few hints:

```cs
users.Add(new User(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
writer.Flush();
```

I'm assuming `users` is of type `List<User>`. That type is not thread safe, so you need a lock when accessing it, or the behavior will be undefined if multiple users log on simultaneously.

```cs
puzzle.guessWord( writer, reader, users );
```

Here, you should forward the current user, not the list of users (that one is in this context global anyway).

```cs
//Creates new User. The player's id indicates which thread the player is using
User user = new User(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

That's wrong. You already created the user for this thread, so use it. The user given in the argument (see above) is the current user.

```cs
                while (gameIsPlaying)
                {
                    string data = reader.ReadLine();
                    //Whatever what writer object print, shows on client side(in putty)
                    writer.WriteLine(TakeGuess(user, data));

                    if (Validation(data).Equals(this.Word))
                    {
                        gameIsPlaying = false;
                        // ...
                    }
                }
```

Here you need to identify the user whose turn it is. So keep a member variable with the ID of the user that is next (note that there's only one instance of the Game class, but it runs many threads). Protect that variable with a lock. On each iteration of the loop, check whether it's our turn. If yes, ask for the guess. If no, output something that says "Please wait for player XY", wait a bit and try again. Of course, you can also do more sophisticated things like using a Semaphore. That would allow users to place guesses whenever they get the lock.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I don't even want you to do it all for me. I just needed a hint, preferably an example of what the answer to my question would probably look like. The main thing for me is to keep 2 and 3 waiting for thread 1

Comment: This might help me I guess?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990651/wait-for-another-thread

Comment: That might partially help. The difference is that in your code, you run the _same code_ for all clients, so you need to track the next action by keeping a local variable about which user the thread is for.

Comment: I have already solved it with semafor, but I will accept your answer, because you gave mi great hints. Thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

I changed the `List<User>` collection to the safer `ConcurrentQueue`

```
ConcurrentQueue<User> users = new ConcurrentQueue<User>();
```

I've initialized the semaphore

```
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1,Environment.ProcessorCount);
```

So the method guessWord() looks like this

```
if (users.Count > 0)
            {
           

            while (gameIsPlaying)
            {
                string data = reader.ReadLine();
                //Whatever what writer object print, shows on client side(in putty)
                writer.WriteLine(TakeGuess(user, data));

                if(winner != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of players in game:" + " " + users.Count);
                    gameIsPlaying = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Winner is user with id" + " " + winner);
                    writer.WriteLine("Winner is user with id" + " " + winner);
                    users.Clear();
                }

                
                if (Validation(data).Equals(this.Word) )
                {
                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                      winner = user.Id;

                    }
                    gameIsPlaying = false;
                }
               
             
            }
        
            writer.WriteLine("The game is over");
```

In method **LoopClient()** in class **Server** I've added these 3 lines to "start the traffic light"

```
                semaphore.WaitOne();
                puzzle.guessWord( writer, reader,users );
                semaphore.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("Now you are out of the game");
```

Comment: *`new Semaphore(1, Environment.ProcessorCount);`* -- Why set the `maximumCount` to `Environment.ProcessorCount`? What's the intention?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias so that more users can connect to the server

Comment: So the `Environment.ProcessorCount` is the maximum number of users that can connect to the server at the same time? And what about the `initialCount: 1`? What does the value `1` represents?

Comment: Yes, that is right. 1 represents single thread that computer use by default